# AngularJS Http Request return 401 from a SailsJS server with Electron

Tags: angularjs, sails.js, electron

I'm building a Electron App. Any request I make with Angular running on the Electron App return with unauthorized.

I already checked for the poilicies from Sails, disabled all policies. If I make a request for the same url from Postman or even Chrome it works ok.

```
$http.get(CONFIG.API + 'auth/login', $scope.login).then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's 100% **config/cors.js** issue. Make sure you have uncommented this line  of code.

`allRoutes: true,`